# Can't detect collision in 3D JavaScript

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision

I am using three.js to make a simulation of the Brownian Motion and I'm stuck on a part where I need to get the little molecules to collide against each other. This is what I have so far:

```
function intersects(sphere, other){  //check if the distance between one sphere and the other is less than radius of both (4)
    var distance = Math.sqrt((sphere.position.x - other.position.x) * (sphere.position.x - other.position.x) +
                             (sphere.position.y - other.position.y) * (sphere.position.y - other.position.y) +
                             (sphere.position.z - other.position.z) * (sphere.position.z - other.position.z));
    if(distance < (4)){
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
}

function checkCollision(current){
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        if(intersects(balls[current], balls[i]) == true){
//          balls[current].velocity.negate();
            alert('hey');
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I know for certain that the balls don't collide/intersect with each other, however I continuously get an alert box. I've tried to check if it's less than (sphere.radius + other.radius) but I don't think that's correct since it didn't seem to work. Also when I do keep it '< 4', it messes up the performance and it starts to run slowly at around 5 fps or less. checkCollision gets used here during the animation, so basically it checks it every time.

```
function animate(){
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){
        balls[i].position.add(balls[i].velocity);
        checkWallBoundaries(i);
        checkCollision(i);
    }

    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
    stats.update();
}
```

I don't know why I can't get this to work. If someone could help me, that'd be greatly appreciated.

edit: Here's a picture of what happens when I uncomment the balls[current].velocity.negate() line https://puu.sh/uG1eS.png. The balls keep going back and forth but they're not even remotely close to each other, so I don't know why collision is being detected

Comment: For performance, why not `return (distance < 4);` and `if(intersects(balls[current], balls[i]))` no need for the extra booleans.  Use a var for each `x - x'` dimension, any `> 4` would guarantee no collision so return immediately. If not then use the var for the `sqrt` rather than calculate twice. Why does `2 * radius` not work, do all your objects have the property set? What configures the simulation is there a global constant you can use?

Comment: I'm not too sure on what you when you say they have property set, but I created them like so: `var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 32, 32);` and here's the full code of creating the sphere if you want to see, https://puu.sh/uG2XA.png. I believe I'm suppose to call it as `balls[i].radius`, but I'm not too sure. Also thank you for your help, gonna fix the checks to add those in.

Comment: Yes [SphereGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments)](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Geometries/SphereGeometry) so the first parameter in your constructor call is the radius. Define `var SPHERE_RADIUS = 2;` and then `new THREE.SphereGeometry(SPHERE_RADIUS, 32, 32)` and your test is `distance < (2*SPHERE_RADIUS)`. If you create balls with different radii then `sphere.radius + other.radius` is needed. Use `console.log` to write out some messages so you can see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it works perfectly now as far as I can tell. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every ball collides with itself. You need to exclude `i === current`

```
for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    if(current === i) continue;
    if(intersects(balls[current], balls[i]) == true){
        alert('hey');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh thank you so much! This should hopefully fix the problem. Do you know how I would come about to excluding it? Since I can't just remove the ball from the list of arrays

Comment: Updated answer to include the check for `current === i`

Comment: Thank you Tashi! So continue basically goes onto the next i iteration and break just exits completely? That's why it worked I assume.

Comment: Stack Overflow has scolded me about having conversations over comments before, but yes, that's the difference between `break` and `continue`.